# Sqlalchemy in-memory database for MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to setup tests for my project and want to use an in memory database for those tests. Based on some examples I found online I've been able to get an in memory sqlite database working...

```
class TestService:
    def setup_method(self) -> None:
        sqlite_shared_name = "test_db_{}".format(
            random.sample(string.ascii_letters, k=4)
        )
        engine = create_engine(
            "sqlite:///file:{}?mode=memory&cache=shared&uri=true".format(
                sqlite_shared_name
            ),
            echo=True,
        )
        self.session = Session(engine)
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

The problem I have is my models are all based around MSSQL (that's what the 'real' code is using) so I get

> ```
> def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>   cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
> ```
>
> E       sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unknown database "dbo"

I also have some specific dialect things brought in for my models

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, DECIMAL, BIGINT
```

Is there any way to get an in memory sqlalchemy engine that works with all these MSSQL functions?

Thanks!

Comment: I dont think this is possible. In order to have a in memory db you need a db that supports that like sqlite. MSSQL is a server-client db and doesn't support in memory db. An option would be to have a MSSQL db setup for testing that gets wiped after the tests complete.

Comment: Relevant read: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/213891

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this your SQL statements would need to changed per-database or made compatible with both.  Note that in SQL Server if you omit the schema name, it will default to the user's default schema, which is typically 'dbo'.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses it really does come down to making sure your statements or declarative models are compatible with both sqlite and your prod db. The only other tripping block I ran into that would be helpful for someone else coming across this is, this platform agnostic GUID column https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/custom_types.html#backend-agnostic-guid-type